# How do I get to move my Light and Camera away from the object

Tags: mesh, camera, lighting, gizmo

I'm having problem moving my light and camera in the scene. Whenever I move them, they keep coming back around the object I created. i've used the gizmo, I've used the G shortcut. I've searched online, checked youtube, tried to know if I could change one or two settings, but it's still not working.

Comment: Maybe you've keyframed them? Please share your file so that we can check: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: As @moonboots says it sounds as if they've got keyframes on them. If you had everything selected rather than just your object and inserted a keyframe with 'I', the camera and light would have been keyframed too.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much. I'm just seeing these comments. That's the kind of problem one faces when he's just a newbie. I just opened a new general file copied my collection and pasted it in the new file and moved on.